# How to Convert Symbolic Transfer Function into zero-pole transfer function?

Tags: matlab, matlab-cvst, matlab-deployment

I am trying to convert my Symbolic transfer function (e.g. `(m.s^2+c.m.s+c.m^2)/s^3+2.m.c.s^2+2.c.s-c^2.m)` into  `zero-pole form like [((s-c/m)(s-2.c.m))/(s-cm)(s-m/2.c)(s-cm)]` by using command `tf2zp` but it is giving

```
error "DOUBLE cannot convert the input expression into a double array.
If the input expression contains a symbolic variable, use VPA."
```

Can somebody help to fix this error because i need pole-zero form in symbolic form. I would be very grateful.

Comment: Are you sure this is a JavaScript problem, not a Matlab one? Please use the appropriate tags.

Answer (score 0):

Symbolic expressions are not read as transfer functions, you need to turn it into a `tf` to be able to use `tf2zp`

I'm not sure about the VPA option but you can try turning the numerator and denominator into vectors by using `sym2poly` and then using them as the `[num, den]` required in `tf2zp`

(this is, assuming `c` and `m` are numeric values. If they are all symbolic I think it might be a bit more complicated)